# How to generate field names and values of JSON dataset in random using for-loop?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code to generate the values of JSON dataset without any problem:

```
  var aData = [];
  for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
    aData.push({
      country: "country" + i,
      GDP: math.round(math.random() * 1000000)
    });
  }
```

But I wish to randomize the names also. I tried below but it doesn't work.

```
  var bData = [];
  for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
      bData.push({
        country: "country" + i,
        "GDP" + j: math.round(math.random() * 1000000)
      });
    }
  };
```

Any suggestion?

.Chap

Comment: FYI - you're creating an array of objects - there is no JSON in your code

Comment: Why do you want different field names?  Wouldn't it just make it harder to access those values?

Comment: Thank you, Jaromanda. Yes, it not JSON. It is just an array of objects. :)

Comment: Thank you, Quant.. I will have another function to read the fields and the corresponding values before render it to our control. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the dynamic key of an object, use `[]` notation instead.

```
var bData = [];
  for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
      var rec = { country: "country" + i };
      rec['GDP'+j] = math.round(math.random() * 1000000);
      bData.push(rec);
    }
  };
```